# Javascript event listeners not firing after page navigation - Rails 5, Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Rails 5, jquery, turbolinks

I have this js code to add an event listener:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  console.log("We're in");
  $('#newsletter_to').change(function(evt) {
    console.log('change');
    window.location = '/registrations/mailchimp_oauth?store_referer=true'; 
  }
}
```

When I first go to the page, the "We're in" message it output to console.

I change the dropdown/select, and "change" is output to the console.

I'm then redirected to an oauth page, as expected.

I click 'Back' in browser, the "We're in" message it output to console.

Change the select, nothing happens.

Any ideas? I've tried adding this to the  but it didn't seem to help:

```
<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">
</head>
```

Comment: can you try with  `$(document).on('change','#newsletter_to',function(){
    console.log('change');
});`

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks!